# Planetary Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, planets

L/m = 7.8e10

2E/m = 0.

Probe is near earth. I checked eccentricity and it is 1--so we know it is a parabola.

As such, how do I find when it is closest to earth? I only know how to do this with elliptical or hyperbolic orbits.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Comment: Your comment lacks congruence with that post. It is not a homework site, yet asking homework questions in an appropriate fashion is acceptable. (Hence the already-created tag). I do not want an answer--I want to be guided. I do have to take a test in December after all. Would you like me to refine my question?

Comment: Your question is asking us to do your work for you; the Meta post I link says these types of questions are not allowed. The types of questions that are allowed here are conceptually based (e.g., "Why do parabolic orbits not have an apogee?"), as explained in the post I link.

Comment: Coolio. Got the answer! Angular momentum. Found a super helpful sight--it's the link above yours in google.

Comment: Btw, Kyle. Where are you a PhD student. You don't say.